# display gif using ION Library

Tags: android, gif, android-ion

I am trying to display gif images using [ION Library](https://github.com/koush/ion)

but it is not working well that is it takes long time to show the animation and the animation of image is not working continuously , the animation plays for few seconds and then stops for some period of time and it keeps going like that.

Activity :

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
Ion.with(imageView).load("http://www.sandiegoairandspace.org/assets/loader.gif");
```

gradle

```
...
...
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'

.....
```

Comment: You cannot use gifs like that, because you actually have to write a little more code to achieve that. Have you took a look at the fresco library from Facebook or Glide? With Glide it is pretty simple, almost a one liner.

Comment: This is how it should work in ion (yes, it's a one liner), your code is correct. Is this the gif in question causing issues?

Comment: @koush : the issue is that 1. long time it takes to load the image , 2. animation of image is not working continuously , the animation plays for few seconds and then stops for some period of time and then plays for fews seconds and then stops for some few seconds and it keeps going on like that............ bye the way it is not a matter of slow internet , i have tried it locally using drawable resources and i faced the same above issues.